# Combing Git Repositories, preserving history AND REFS

Tags: git

I have several Git repos which I want to merge into one.  I have found several articles on the web, like

- https://passingcuriosity.com/2015/combining-git-repositories/
- https://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/merging-two-git-repositories/
- https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/

They are getting the commit graphs of different repos by fetching them as remote.

However by looking at the steps, it seems to be that although commit history is preserved, the refs are not.

What I want is:

- Assume I have 2 repos, `foo` and `bar`
- I want the histories of them to exists in the `combined` repo
- In the new `combined` repo, I want to be able to refer existing branches and tags in `foo` with `foo/` as suffix.  So that if there are same tag `v1.0` in both `foo` and `bar`, it becomes `foo/v1.0` and `bar/v1.0` in the `combined` repo

I am thinking of this way and would like to clarify with experts to make sure it works:

1. Have both `foo` and `bar` repos cloned locally, with tags fetched
2. Create a new `combined` repository with an initial commit
3. Copy `foo` and `bar`'s `.git/objects` to `combined/.git/objects` (This should bring in all blobs, trees and commits of `foo` and `bar` to `combined` right?)
4. copy `foo/.git/refs/remotes/origin/*` to  `combined/.git/refs/heads/foo/*`. Do similar thing for `foo/.git/refs/tags/*`
5. Repeat 4 for `bar` repository
6. Copy the updated `.git/refs` and `.git/logs/refs/heads` (excluding `.git/logs/refs/remote`) of both `foo` and `bar` to `combined`
7. Merging `foo/master` to `master`, and move everything to `foo/`
8. Do the same for `bar`

It looks to me that it is going to work but I am worried I may have overlooked something which may ruin the repository, that's why I am asking for opinion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use remotes and going through `git` commands will help you avoid reverse engineering pitfalls.

For example : somme refs are actually stored in `.git/packed-refs`, and you should not forget to take them into account.

(Now that this point is outlined, the problem is spotting the *other* points we didn't outline ;) )

---

You can edit the refspec of the `foo` remote (resp. `bar`) to something like `+refs/*:refs/foo/*` (resp. `+refs/*:refs/bar/*`),

or rather :

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/foo/* # map foo branches to local branches named 'foo/*'
+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/foo/*   # map foo tags to local tags named 'foo/*'
```

then simply run `git fetch`, and you should be close to good.

---

This wouldn't keep the reflog for each branch, you may have to do some manual hack here.

Comment: Of course I can use reomte as suggested in the links in my questions, and use script to rename every branch/tag one by one, and then do the same for next remote.  However it seems cumbersome to me.  What could be the problem if I manipulate the `.git` as what I was thinking above?

Comment: it's just : going through the official api (e.g `git` commands) will lead to less bugs than reverse engineering the implementation. For example : using `git clone / git fetch` ensures that `git` actually lists all the references (some are stored in `packed-refs` for example)

Comment: (for your update) existence of `refs/remotes/foo` is meaningless as once I published this repo for our team to use, they are not going to have same remotes as my combined one.  I want to make it possible to have tags/branches of the original repository in the new combined repository

Comment: Good point for the packed-refs.  Seems couldn't go for a shortcut... :(  thanks

Comment: (I was looking for a decent way to do what you want) : use the refspec for each remote

Comment: Thanks, heads seems slightly clearer with refspecs.  Still struggling on how to deal with tags

Comment: Have you tried the two lines refspec in my last edits ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182566/discussion-between-legec-and-adrian-shum).

Comment: It works GREAT!  Terrific tips in making use of refspec in a way that I never thought off